# Modify existing Solr 7.6.0 / Lucene index (add another field 'URL' to an already indexed file (.pdf, .docx etc.))

Tags: indexing, solr, lucene

I have a Solr 7.6.0 Lucene index (lots of .pdf's, .docx and .xlsx files)

The index was created using the post command in a command window, pointing to a directory share (mapped filepath) where the files exist.

There is also a web URL for the document which I have in a database and Lucene currently knows nothing about.  I would like to 'enrich' the existing index with this URL data.

Can I extract the id of the currently indexed files and then use the Solr web interface to modify the existing index, injecting the URL?

I am looking at the following tutorial for advice:
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/apache_solr/apache_solr_indexing_data.htm

The tutorial shows an example of adding a document but not modifying one.

Comment: You can [modify a single field](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/updating-parts-of-documents.html), but it'll require all your existing fields to be set as `stored="true"` - assuming you're using Solr. It'll also require running a Solr version that supports atomic updates.

Comment: Thanks @MatLindh  I am using Solr 7.6.0 (added to original question).  Not all my fields are stored.  _text_ for example is only indexed.  Will that be a problem?

Comment: `_text_` is usually generated from a `copyField` statement. All the fields that aren't defined as copyField destinations must be stored, however - otherwise the value of that field is lost.

Comment: I see.  Thank you... I'll give it a go then and see what happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @MatsLindh I managed to get it to work:

I used the `Solr` GUI to run the `JSON` `add-field` update:

```
{
    "add-field" : {
    "name":"URL",
    "type":"string",
    "stored":true
    "indexed":true
    }
}
```

I then inserted/set the property:

```
{"id":"S:\\Docs\\forIndexing\\indexThisFile_001.pdf",
 "URL":{"set":"https//localhost/urlToFiles/indexThisFile_001.pdf:"}
}
```